# Unable to create Endeca Application

Tags: endeca

I have installed Endeca ( in Linux ) and am now trying to create an application. On trying to initialize services I am getting an error which is as follows

**Caused by com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.exception.EacCommunicationException
com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.application.Application setDefinition - Caught exception while defining application 'MediaStoreen'.
Caused by com.endeca.eac.client.EACFault
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl newInstance0 - null**

I checked the application logs & found more information on the error, which is as follows

**INFO: Setting definition for application 'MediaStoreen'.
Feb 15, 2013 2:38:04 PM com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.Controller execute
SEVERE: Caught an exception while checking provisioning.
com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.exception.EacCommunicationException: Caught exception while defining application 'MediaStoreen'.
        at com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.application.Application.setDefinition(Application.java:141)
        at com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.Controller.provision(Controller.java:667)
        at com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.Controller.execute(Controller.java:235)
        at com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.Controller.main(Controller.java:134)
Caused by: An error occurred while trying to create the application: Error connecting to  `http://hostname:8888/eac-agent/IDelegateServer`: Could not invoke service.. Nested exception is org.codehaus.xfire.fault.XFireFault: Server returned error code = 404 for URI : `http://hostname:8888/eac-agent/IDelegateServer`. Check server logs for details**

I understand the error, but don't know what can I do to resolve it. Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the PlatformServices is running?

Answer (score 5):

To work around this problem:

- Stop the Endeca HTTP Service
- Create a back up of the **state** folder in *PlatformServices/workspace*
- Create an empty **state** folder (Optional)
- Start the Endeca HTTP Service
- Now remove the state folder after initializing your services (using **initialize_services.sh --force** )

Doing this resolved my problem. Not sure why this error occurred. Would be nice if some one could tell the cause of this issue.

Comment: This is not the correct solution. 
The issue happens even if the "state" folder is empty.
This happens because PlatformServices is not running (either due to ENDECA_CONF not being set correctly, or the linux user does not have execute permissions on PlatformServices startup script).

Answer (score 0):

**ROOT CAUSE**:

This issue usually occurs on LINUX machine, when your PlatformServices is not started. Endeca PlatformServices usually does not start automatically (and fails) when either

1. Your user does not have execute permissions on PlatformServices Startup script
2. Your **ENDECA_CONF** variable is not set.

**HOW TO FIX?**

1. Shut down all Endeca Services (PlatformServices, ToolsAndFrameworks, CAS)
2. Now set the environment variable **ENDECA_CONF** as */opt/Endeca/PlatformServices/workspace* [Replace as per your path]
3. Now, start the services one by one in the sequence **PlatformServices**, **ToolsAndFrameworks** and **CAS**

You should be able to create your app now. For more details you can also have a look at an article here: http://learnoracleatg.blogspot.in/2017/05/unable-to-create-endeca-application-eac-communication-exception.html